# Pointer best practice

Tags: c, pointers

I am just starting to learn C and (of course) struggling with pointers :)

Given this snippet:

```
int *storage, *storage_p;
storage = malloc(sizeof(int[GROW_BY]));
storage_p = storage;
// do something with storage, using storage_p
free(storage);
storage = NULL;
```

Is it really necessary to have two variables declared to work with the `malloc()`'ed data? Is it good practice to create a `storage` and `storage_p` the way I did? If not, what would would be 'the way'?

Comment: Not quite your question, but it *is* good practise to NULL the pointers you have freed or you know you are not going to need again from this piece of code.

Comment: Code is dangerous when two pointer point to same memory and one is freed.

Comment: @ndim: I know, every reference I have read about pointers, that is very clearly stated! Edit: I now see that you mean I should also NULL storage_p, I will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a pointer that will hold the value returned by malloc(), so that you can free it later.

If what you plan on using storage_p for is going to change it value, then you are going to need two pointers.

However, I generally keep the pure initial pointer, and create new ones, ad hoc, as I need one.

```
int *storage = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int[GROW_BY])); 
// :
int* ptr = storage;
while (*ptr)
{
  // :
  ++ptr;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly my case. I used `storage` in a loop (incrementing it) and when i invoked `free()` I got a segfault. I guess my description wasn't clear enough.. So to recap, normally you don't create a copy unless you have to modify the pointer. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

I would only duplicate a pointer that was created by malloc for one reason: I want to modify it.

For example, If you were iterating through a character array you allocated with malloc, I would copy the pointer to a new variable to iterate through and leave the first one untouched.

Also when it comes to dynamic allocation, take a look at free lists, they simplify a lot:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not having copies of pointers around. It just increases the chance of having a dangling free pointer that you may accidentally use later, or an extra copy you may not mean to free, or an extra copy you may not mean to double-free. I don't personally see a need for `storage_p` here.

Gool 'ol:

```
int *storage = malloc(size_of_whatever);
storage[0] = do_something();
free(storage);
storage = NULL;
```

would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't see where you've gained anything by having both `storage` and `storage_p`. I'd normally just have one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you might want to do this is because after you do a few manipulations with `storage`, you may not remember what to `free()`. Having `storage_p` as a copy that you never modify helps prevent memory leaks because you can call `free(storage_p)` later regardless of what happened to `storage`. Whether this outweighs the disadvantages already mentioned depends on details of the situation.

An example:

```
int *storage;
storage = malloc(sizeof(int[GROW_BY]));
storage++;
free(storage); //SEGFAULT or MEMORY LEAK or OTHER BAD STUFF
storage = NULL;
```

vs

```
int *storage, *storage_p;
storage = malloc(sizeof(int[GROW_BY]));
storage_p = storage;
storage++;
free(storage_p);
storage_p=NULL;
storage = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems unnecessary to me. I'm not sure what the middle section might be, but I can't see any benefit to aliasing the pointers like that -- unless you're modifying storage_p (for example, incrementing it to iterate). In fact, having two aliased pointers could make it more difficult to keep track of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherent reason to reassign the space which was malloc'd to another pointer.

If anything, it will just needlessly add lines and compromise readability.