# Using file pointers correctly

Tags: c, pointers, fopen, fclose

I have a basic question about file pointers. In the code below i have a while loop followed by a for loop. The for loop only will show the line count unless i **fopen** the file again - is that normal? and if so should i **fclose** it after the while loop beforehand? There's probably some "rewind" function that i'm unaware of, so my whole approach might be wrong. I realize both the while loop and for can be combined, but this my question is about the **fopen**, **fclose** and using the data again from **fopen**.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 200

enum { MAXLINES = 200 };
char lpath[MAXLINES][BUFSIZ];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

        char c;
        int l = 0, n = 0, i = 0, count = 0;
        char lines[MAXLINES][BUFSIZ];

        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (fp == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to open input.txt\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        while (l < MAXLINES && fgets(lines[l], sizeof(lines[0]), fp)) {
                lines[l][strlen(lines[l])-1] = '\0';
                puts(lines[l]);
                l++;
        }

        // fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // below won't output unless fopen again
        for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
            if (c == '\n') { 
                count++;

        }
        printf(">> line count: %i", count);

        fclose(fp);
}
```

looked also at: [Pointer best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312408/pointer-best-practice)

Comment: 1) Better use `fgetc`. 2) `both return an `int`, not a `char. 3) Therefore your `EOF` test is wrong and will always fail if `char` is unsigned!

Comment: @Olaf: I got that code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4237107/5905926, so maybe let them know too ... thanks

Comment: "There's probably some "rewind" function  that i'm unaware of" - there is! And it is, in fact, called "rewind".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's normal, you need to `rewind()` the file. The problem is that when the `for` loop start the file has reached the end, so reads will fail and `feof()` will return non-zero.

Two options

```
rewind(fp);
```

Or

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

When you call `fopen()` again you leak resources because you overwrite the pointer and now you can't `fclose()` the first `fopen()`ed file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rewind()` as @iharob suggested, or you could just close and re-open the file:

```
while (l < MAXLINES && fgets(lines[l], sizeof(lines[0]), fp)) {
            lines[l][strlen(lines[l])-1] = '\0';
            puts(lines[l]);
            l++;
}

fclose(fp);
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // below won't output unless fopen again
for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
    if (c == '\n') { 
        count++;
    }
}
```